# Correcting for sample overlap (loss of statistical independence) in two z-tests

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, mathematical-statistics

**Short form**: How can I correct two p-values computed from normal distributions to account for the fact that part of the samples overlap?

**Long form**:
I have a sequence of i.i.d RVs of length $n$. The sum of a randomly chosen subsequence with sufficient length is normally distributed.

I would like to compute the probability that at least **one out of two** randomly chosen subsequences with lengths $k,l \lt n$ has a sum of $\geq y$. The problem: The subsequences are overlapping, i.e. they have $m$ items from the original sequence in common, and are therefore not statistically independent.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is $m$ constant and known?

Comment: @January Yes, $m$ would be constant and known, and $0 \lt m \lt min(k,l)$